# Using Dropbox API with access token only

Tags: c#, .net, api, dropbox

I want to do silent uploads, without the need of authorization. I've already authorized my app, I've got my access token (which Dropbox now can show it to you in it's account app settings). I just want to use some form of API to communicate with Dropbox without app secret and app key, as those already gave me access token. I've tried REST, Dropnet, SharpBox. Using C#. Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4):

The dropbox API documentation on file uploading is here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

To use the access token you have to put it in the HTTP Headers when you make the upload request, your header should include like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer <myToken>
```

Then Dropbox will auth using the token found in the header and upload the file.